# ssl.SSLZeroReturnError: TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:661)

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, python-sockets, python-socketio

This is my code:

import ssl, socket
server ='10.10.10.9'

port = 50443

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ssl_sock =ssl.wrap_socket(sock,ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3)

ssl_sock.connect((server, port))

return ssl_sock

I am Getting below error:

File "/home/ragav/trunk/lib/Ipdu.py", line 35, in open_socket

```
ssl_sock.connect((server, port))
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 876, in connect

```
self._real_connect(addr, False)
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 867, in _real_connect

```
self.do_handshake()
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 840, in do_handshake

```
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
```

ssl.SSLZeroReturnError: TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:661)

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to openssl version. check your openssl version if its 0.9 then that might be a reason for the error.
You can check openssl version in your python code using

```
print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
```